# Is there a better way to subtract 2 bitmap images?

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing, bitmap

the user draws an image on another outlined image
finally when he is done i want to subtract the outline image from the drawn image to reduce the size of the stored image in the sqlite database.

i'm just doing this because it's logical to not have repetitive data in each stored item so here is what i'm thinking of doing

```
Bitmap SubtractBitmap(Bitmap originalImg, Bitmap otherImg)
{
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(originalImg);

    for (int i = 0; i < result.Height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < result.Width; j++)
        {
            if (otherImg.GetPixel(j, i) != System.Drawing.Color.Transparent)
            {
                result.SetPixel(j,i,System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

and i'm probably compressing it after that so i think the transparent pixels will reduce the size as the original image will still probably have 50% or more transparent pixels

Comment: If I were you I'd finish the proof of concept so it's no longer just an idea. Once you've walked the whole path, you will probably be able to ask more specific questions.

Comment: You have tagged the question WPF, but the Bitmap class is Winforms. Why aren't you using the corresponding WPF types, i.e. BitmapSource and derived?

Comment: i actually didn't know Bitmap isn't a WPF thing, thanks for letting me know also it looks more complicated to edit pixels with it but it's probably the right way

Comment: Besides that, it is much more efficient to operate on the bitmap's raw pixel buffer, instead of retrieving and storing single pixels. For BitmapSource, use the CopyPixels method to get the buffer and use the Create method to create a new BitmapSource from a modified buffer. For buffer modification you need to know the pixel format, i.e. how a single pixel maps to set of bytes in the buffer. Use the BitmapSource's Format property. You may also want to take a look at WriteableBitmap, a class derived from BitmapSource.